# Set controller scope value as global

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS project.
in my login controller i've set user values in to `localStorageService.set("user", res)` when user loging success,it direct to profile html and controlling by Profile controller.in their i have `$scope.user = localStorageService.get("user");` 
currently i can access this `user` only inside profile html.but i want to access this globally.
eg: in my header html.

how to set this to access in every ware in my project html pages?

**Login controller**

```
mymedApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $filter, $http, $window, $document, Common, localStorageService, SweetAlert, Facebook) {

$scope.user = {
    user_id : "",
    first_name : "",
    last_name : "",

  };

    $scope.login = function () {
        Common.get('mobile/signin', $scope.login, function (res, err) {
          if (res.user_id > 0) {
            localStorageService.set("user", res);

            $rootScope.$emit('profileChanged', function () {
              $window.location.href = '#/' + profile.js;
            });
          } else {
            SweetAlert.error("Login request failed, please check the email and password and try again.", {
              title : "Login Failed!",
              confirmButtonColor : '#e74c3c'
            });
          }
        }, true);
      };

)};
```

**Profile Controller**

```
myApp.controller('ProfileController', function ($scope, $filter, $rootScope, $http, $window, $document, localStorageService,) {
        var init = function () {
                if (!localStorageService.get("user")) {
                   // $window.location.href = '#/login';
                } else {
                    $scope.user = localStorageService.get("user");

                }
            };

            init();
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post localStorageService , how you are storing this value??

Comment: You can use $rootScope intend of  $scope

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing this in localstorage Service it is available globally. You can inject the localstorage service in your desired controller and get it by the same way.

```
 if (!localStorageService.get("user")) {
                   // $window.location.href = '#/login';
                } else {
                    $scope.user = localStorageService.get("user");

                }
```

Comment: there is no controller for my header html.just html file

Comment: Do you have a main controller for index file apart from the partial views controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can set,

```
var user = localStorageService.get("user");
```

and then set this user variable in a session like,

```
Session.setValue(variable name(username),user);
```

and then in which page you want to get that value you can get

```
Session.getValue(variable name which written during set session(username));
```